# Why does the .env file get added to build/web/assets?

Tags: flutter, environment-variables, flutter-web, dotenv, flutter-dotenv

I'm using flutter_dotenv to manage some API keys - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv

According to the instructions I should add the .env file to assets in pubspec.yaml but when I run `flutter build web` it adds the .env file to the build for deployment. This doesn't seem correct to me because the .env file should not get deployed anywhere publicly from what I understand.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and solved it by renaming `.env.*` files to `env.*`.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv#usage

> Note: If deploying to web server, ensure that the config file is uploaded and not ignored. (Whitelist the config file on the server, or name the config file without a leading .)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems too. What I misunderstood from documentation, the 'assets' section is a child of the 'flutter' section in the `pubspec.yml` file.

So, it should look like:

```
flutter:
    assets:
        - .env
```

Comment: You have to understand the question first, then answer if you know the correct answer